# Birth and death process, and calculating waiting time using Little's law

Tags: stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution, queueing

> Assume that an individual only has two possible states: susceptible (S) and infected (I). Further, assume that the individuals in the population are independent, and that for each susceptible individual the time until the next infection follows an exponential distribution with expected value 1/λ = 100 days and that the durations of the infections follow independent exponential distributions with expected values 1/μ = 7 days.
>
> a) Let Y (t) denote the number of infected individuals in the population at time t measured in days. Specify the birth and death rates of this birth and death process.
>
> The total population contains 5.26 million individuals.
>
> b) Assume the stochastic process {Y (t) : t ≥ 0} has reached its stationary distribution. For each infection, there is a probability of 1% that the infection will result in serious compli- cations that requires hospitalization. On average, the hospitals only have capacity to handle 2000 individuals with complications from a cold. Use Little’s law to calculate the average treatment time required to not exceed the capacity.

So for a) the birth rates should decrease with an increase in the amount of infected individuals, however the overall population size remains the same in this model, so Im thinking the birth rate is just  and the death rate simply ? Or should the death rate be  and birth rate / where  is the number of infected individuals?

For b) Im not sure what I need to calculate. From what I see we can just plug straight in to Little's law = and put =2000
and use the  given to solve for , however the answer obtained that way makes no sense.

Comment: Computing the stationary distribution when the population is 5.26 million seems intractable to me...